# Is there a easier way to retrieve a index name from a Series object while boolean indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm just learning python and doing some exercises. One exercise is to retrieve the country name (as a string) with the highest life expectancy and by using boolean indexing. The data frame given has the index column set to the countries names.

This is the best I got because I can't figure out a way to retrieve the specific index name without resetting the index from a Series object.

`(df[world_data["life expectancy"] == max(world_data["life expectancy"])] == True).reset_index().iloc[0,0]`

It seems though that this is a bit long, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: share some data, with expected output

Comment: Use `df[world_data["life expectancy"].idxmax()`